# MySQL 'multiple rows' from two joins challenge

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, group-concat

I have the following MySQL query joining two additional tables..

```
SELECT  plants.plant_id,
        plants.scientific_name,
        plants_features.features,
        plants_features.features_id

FROM    plants_features,
        plants2features,
        plants

WHERE   plants_features.features_id = plants2features.features_id

AND     plants2features.plant_id = plants.plant_id
```

and I was happy with the output.

```
plant_id,scientific_name,features,features_id
3,"Actaea matsumurae 'White Pearl' (Bugbane)","colourful fruit",6
11,"Heuchera 'Beauty Colour' (Coral bells)","salt resistant/coastal",15
18,"Phyllostachys nigra (Black bamboo)","colourful bark",5
26,"Carex morrowii 'Silver Sceptre' (Japanese sedge)","drought tolerant",18
27,"Heuchera 'Obsidian' (Coral bells)","salt resistant/coastal",15
29,"Dianella tasmanica 'Tas Red' (Flax lily)","drought tolerant",18
38,"Stipa tenuissima (Mexican feather grass)","attractive seed-heads",2
38,"Stipa tenuissima (Mexican feather grass)","invasive/self seed/suckering",13
```

You can see from the plant_id '38' (bottom two rows) that it's outputting more than one row per record.

My question is guys, can you please advise what exactly the new MySQL query needs to be to ensure multiple rows are in one record by 'plant_id'?

Thanks in advance,
Richard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need grouping and [`aggregation functions`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html). You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get comma separated list:

```
SELECT  plants.plant_id,
        plants.scientific_name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(plants_features.features) AS features,
        GROUP_CONCAT(plants_features.features_id) AS feature_ids
FROM plants_features
JOIN plants2features
  ON plants_features.features_id = plants2features.features_id
JOIN plants
  ON plants2features.plant_id = plants.plant_id
GROUP BY plants.plant_id, plants.scientific_name;
```

Also use `JOIN` syntax instead of comma and where.

Comment: Thank you so much lad2025 that worked brilliantly, I just removed the second GROUP_CONCAT as it wasn't actually required.

You have made my week! First post here on StackOverflow and and answered very quickly.